# I need to sum the counts of two different columns into one grand total

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Tables]

I have the two tables as shown and I need to count the distinct number of classifications (F,M,O) and the distinct number of statuses (GL,PD) and list the total of each and then a grand total of all types. I can't seem to get the total right, it always comes out to 242 when it should be 22.

[image: The results I get]

```
select crimes.classification, count(crimes.classification) as 'classifications/statuses'
from crimes
group by classification
union all
select crime_charges.charge_status, count(crime_charges.charge_status)
from crime_charges
group by charge_status
union all
select 'Total', count(crime_charges.charge_status) + count(crimes.classification)
from crime_charges, crimes;
```

Comment: please don't post image use text

Comment: `from crime_charges, crimes` This is old join style . And you are doing a `CROSS JOIN` here

Answer (score 0):

Define the initial query as a common table expression (CTE) which may then be referenced by a subsequent CTE to calculate the totals.

```
WITH details
AS (
    SELECT 1 AS source
        , crimes.classification
        , count(crimes.classification) AS [classifications/statuses]
    FROM crimes
    GROUP BY classification
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT 1 AS source
        , crime_charges.charge_status AS classification
        , count(crime_charges.charge_status) AS [classifications/statuses]
    FROM crime_charges
    GROUP BY charge_status
    )
, totals AS (
    SELECT 2 AS source
        , 'Total' AS classification
        , sum([classifications/statuses]) AS [classifications/statuses]
    FROM details
    )

SELECT source, classification, [classifications/statuses]
FROM details

UNION ALL

SELECT source, classification, [classifications/statuses]
FROM totals
ORDER BY source, classification
```